# Strange malware div injected to browsers, what to do?

Tags: flash, malware

So a few days ago I started to get popups on my  wordpress site, and I went trough it and removed everything I could find, updated wordpress, changed all my theme files, and went trough it all. Got rid of the popups, and my host scanned it and cleared it for me.

Today I noteced a div was injected after my html, and I though I had missed something. Spend a few hours going trough everything, when I realized this isn't on my wordpress installation, I have this div injected on any site I go to, with both chrome and Safari so it must be some kind of Browser Hijack?

This is the div injected:

```
<div id="dp_swf_engine" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"><embed 
style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
src="http://www.ajaxcdn.org/swf.swf" width="1" height="1" id="_dp_swf_engine" 
name="_dp_swf_engine" bgcolor="#336699" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always"></div>
```

Im on a os x system, and use Safari and Chrome. Have anyone seen this before?

Comment: Ajaxcdn does not appear to be malware: http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swf.swf that gets downloaded from that link *appears* to consist entirely of Google Analytics code. I say that after looking at it for 2-3 minutes with [Adobe SWF Investigator](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/swfinvestigator.html). If you need a more in-depth analysis of that code you should probably hire someone to do that.

Additionally Virus Total does not report any issues with that swf: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9250c809bc8d4ed6dd80beb10ec0dbd4281fc42c40563a68be050767e42514f7/analysis/1410348821/

Comment: I guess you where right guys! Never seen it before, and it appeared after I did have an attack on my wordpress site, so I assumed it belonged, especieally when I googled it and malware topics about it came up. Anyways, deleted extensions in both browser and is gone. Thanks guys.

Comment: I did reverese engineer this SWF once and I subscribe to Respawned's comment - this file is purely for web tracking purposes. It's a bit murky because it attempts to bypass standard cookie controls by using Flash, but otherwise harmless.